# Android share app private files

Tags: android, file, share, private

Is it possible to share through Intent some audio files to other apps like telegram, google drive, whatsapp ?
My files are being downloaded and kept into my app private folder, like: /data/user/0/myPackage/app_NameOfFolder/file.mp3

I wrote this simple method:

```
    public void sendSound(String fileToSend){
    try{

        Log.d(TAG,"Sending: " + fileToSend);
        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        Uri audioUri = Uri.parse(fileToSend);
        sharingIntent.setType("audio/*");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, audioUri);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share"));

    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("TAG",e.getMessage());
        Log.d("TAG",e.toString());
    }

}
```

But i'm not able to share it, getting error:"unable to share please retry"
If i move the file into a public directory, like: `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getPath() +"/file.mp3";`

It works, so i think it's something related to permission, so this is my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Dunno what am i doing wrong tho.

Comment: Sorry not possible

Comment: You can try to share your files **as generic files** by attaching them to an eMail intent. By using an `intent chooser`, you will be able to choose which app to use to send it out.

Answer (score 5):

Third-party apps have no rights to your portion of [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html).

Most likely, you can [use `FileProvider`](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/index.html) to make this content available to other apps, at least if your file is somewhere under `getFilesDir()` or `getCacheDir()`.

Comment: All right i will give it a try, thank you for trying to point me out to a solution.

Comment: well I'm trying similar [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46789824/2624806). Any suggestion what I'm missing ?