# Share audio file from /data/user/0/ directory using FileProvider

Tags: android, audio, android-intent, android-fileprovider, android-sharing

I'm using [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) API for sharing content actually storing in internal storage.

Following is my xml configuration that linked with Provider configured in Manifiest file.

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <cache-path name="xs_audio" path="/audio/records"/>
</paths>
```

and code that I'm using to share is following:

```
    private final static String FILE_PROVIDER = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".fileprovider";
        
    private String testPackageAppHaveAccess = "com.whats";
            public static void shareDocument(Activity activity, CallRecordData data) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Record File");
                intent.setType("audio/*");
        
                ArrayList<Uri> files = new ArrayList<>();
                //for (AudioModelObj image : data.getDocuments()) {
                    files.add(getImageUri(activity, data.getFile()));
                //}
        
                activity.grantUriPermission(testPackageAppHaveAccess, files.get(0), Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, files);
                activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Audio File."));
            }
        
            private static Uri getImageUri(Activity activity, String audioURI) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 24) {
                    return Uri.parse(audioURI);
                } else {
                    URI uri = URI.create(audioURI);
                    File file = new File(uri);
                    return FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity, FILE_PROVIDER, file);
                }
            }
}
```

but while launching with app it's not attaching anything. In case of gmail it say "can't attach empty file". File is confirmedly available as I'm displaying list of file and playing.

For reference: Uri generating from getImageUri(..) is

> /data/user/0/com.xl.cl.debug/cache/audio/records/17-10-17_170728_abc_.wav

Any suggestion what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Google's FileProvider is messy and confusing as if a junior developer has designed it.  Google claims to be the ultimate Android authority but it lacks even the basic competencies...

Answer (score 3):

- `<files-path>` already points to what on some devices will be `/data/user/0/com.xl.cl.debug`
- `<cache-path>` is what you should be using, replacing `path` with just the subdirectory of interest (`audio/records`), eliminating the `/data/user/0/com.xl.cl.debug/cache` bit
- You are calling `grantUriPermission()`, where the first parameter is not a package
- You are calling `grantUriPermission()`, where the first parameter is not a package identifying the app to which you are trying to grant permission
- You are not adding `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` to the `Intent`, which is the typical way of saying "the `Uri` in this `Intent` should be readable by the recipient of this `Intent`" (though it is possible that `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` requires more work here, as I haven't played with that much)
- No filesystem path in the human history has begun with `content:/`, so get rid of that
- Calling `new File()` and supplying a value that is not a filesystem path is not going to work well

There may be more problems than those, but that should get you started

Comment: AFAIK, as per [**developer doc**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html#Permissions) _activity.grantUriPermission_ is right, it should call with Context object. And adding package name of apps to whom it should allow sharing isn't something will be hardcode as while user can have multiple application. Please check I have update the question.

Comment: Also I wanted to share an audio file, is this a right approach ?

Comment: @code: Get rid of the URI and just create the File. Use a specific MIME type, not a wildcard. And you might start with a simple ACTION_SEND and a single Uri to start.

Comment: _Get rid of the URI and just create the File_ But how that will be share then ? Any suggested example !!

Comment: @CoDe: Get rid of `URI uri = URI.create(audioURI);`. Replace the following line with `File file = new File(audioURI);`. Part of your problem is that you think that `/data/user/0/com.xl.cl.debug/cache/audio/records/17-10-17_170728_abc_.wav` is a URI, and it is not. It is a filesystem path.